# How can I upload a list of images from a folder into my xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, image-processing, image-uploading

Not sure if it's possible, but it sounds reasonable.

I have a list of images in a folder on my desktop that I would like my Xcode project to upload/import. Can I do it dynamically as I will be adding images consistently in the near future, instead of having to upload each image individually? Can anyone advise me how to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it a little difference:

1. Create a physical folder reference in Xcode.  This folder should have a blue color instead of the yellow color.
2. Create an alias from above folder and put it on your Desktop.
3. As you put your imnages files into the alias on your Desktop, those files will show up automatically in the Xcode project.

Comment: and then how can i import them dynamically into say.. a table? is that possible?

Comment: Since this was not part of your original question, I would post another question about this and perhaps a little more precise description so others can compete with answers and you will get the best of solution.

Comment: I'll do that. But fyi, it was the second part of the question where it says "can i do it dynamically", but thanks for your feedback, much appreciated!